# How to trace ETW Events inside Parallel.ForEach in C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, etw, plinq

Need your help to understand how can we log ETW events to track Task started & Task completed inside parallel.foreach. I basically need to see when event got fired.

I have gone through few examples which are available in web but not able to use it inside parallel.foreach.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/etw-events-in-task-parallel-library-and-plinq

Below is code snippet where I want to trace the ETW events. Thanks for your help & suggestion.

```
        List<int> integerList = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).ToList();
        Parallel.ForEach(integerList, i =>
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Print of i = {0}, thread = {1},thread status = {2}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


                Console.WriteLine(@" Catch value of Exception = {0},Thread Id {1},Thread State {2}", ex.ToString(), Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState);
            }
            finally {
                Console.WriteLine(@" Finally block value of i = {0}, thread = {1},thread status = {2}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState);
            }
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Task started/completed"? Each individual invocation of the delegate? When the parallel loop starts using a new thread? Parallel.For/Foreach are not really task-oriented the same way as async/await, so your question does not make that much sense to me.

Comment: "The data model for ETW data is non-trivial..." https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/blob/main/documentation/TraceEvent/TraceEventLibrary.md Are you sure you want to use ETW for this? In what way does traditional diagnostic logging not work for your use case?

Comment: In Visual Studio press Alt+F2 - open Debug > Performance Profiler. Select Event Viewer checkbox. Press Start button. All ETW events will be collected in diagnostics session.

Comment: Why the question? Tasks aren't threads and `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't create a separate tasks per item either. It partitions the input and uses roughly one worker task per virtual core to process the data. This reduces the synchronization cost between threads which is the *biggest* obstacle to parallelization. Knowing when the workers started and finished isn't useful - it could easily be that they started when `Parallel.ForEach` was first called and finished when it completed

Comment: If you want to see when items are really processed, use Visual Studio's [Concurrency Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer?view=vs-2022). This will help detect [common problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/common-patterns-for-poorly-behaved-multithreaded-applications?view=vs-2022) like contention or oversubscription. The timeline views are better than any list of ETW events